# How to store a value in an array only if unique

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm writing a PHP report which is designed to be exported purely as a CSV file, using commma delimiters.

There are three columns relating to product_id, these three columns are as follows:

```
SKU                Parent / Child      Parent SKU
12345                  parent             12345
12345_1                child              12345
12345_2                child              12345
12345_3                child              12345
12345_4                child              12345
18099                  parent             18099
18099_1                child              18099
```

At the moment the code looks like this:

```
<?php

    $con_size = array (35,355,36,37,375,38,385,39,395,40,405,41,415,42,425,43,435,44,445,45,455,46,465,47,475,48,485);
    $arrlength=count($con_size);

    for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++) {

    // check if size is available
    if($line['quantity_c_size_'.$con_size[$x].'_chain'] > 0 ) {

      ?>

        <? echo 'Shoes'; ?>,
        <?=$line['product_id']?>,
        ,
        ,
```

So at the moment this is simply echoing out the product_ID into the SKU column. How would I create an array which tests whether the 'product_id' is unique and if not suffixes the ID with _1, _2, etc.

Thanks,

Comment: Try [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array)

Comment: Use if(!in_array()){} in a loop, and add it to the array if it's not in the loop.

Comment: what wrong with in_array

Comment: Another option would be to add a built up SELECT unioning together all the values already in the array, and then using a LEFT OUTER JOIN to only select items which are not already in the array.

Comment: If you're asking a separate question, please ask a separate question, rather than changing this one in such a manner as to invalidate existing answers.

Comment: @TRiG - Sorry, I'll create a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test whether it's in the array, and add it if it's not.

```
if (!in_array($line['product_id'], $SKU)) {
    $SKU[] = $line['product_id'];
    echo $line['product_id'];
} else {
    echo $line['product_id'] . "_1";
}
```

If you need the suffixes to increment each time, you can do:

```
$SKU_counters = array();
if (isset($SKU_counters[$line['product_id']])) {
    echo $line['product_id'] . "_" . $SKU_counters[$line['product_id']]++;
} else {
    echo $line['product_id'];
    $SKU_counters[$line['product_id']] = 1;
}
```

At the end of the loop you do:

```
$SKU = array_keys($SKU_counters);
```

Comment: So this replaces the array_push statement? Thanks

Comment: Yes, of course. `$SKU[] = ` is the same as `array_push($SKU, )`

Comment: See updated answer. If you meant that the suffix should change for each repetition, you'll need to make an associative array that contains the current suffix, and use that.

Comment: better to use the ID as the array key. a simple key lookup is MUCH cheaper than the ever-worse in_array search loop.

Comment: Whether it's worth it depends on how big the array will get. Anyway, my second solution uses an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly putting most of the work onto the database (not tested):-

```
<?php

$con_size = array (35,355,36,37,375,38,385,39,395,40,405,41,415,42,425,43,435,44,445,45,455,46,465,47,475,48,485);

$con_check = 'AND (quantity_c_size_'.implode('_chain > 0 OR quantity_c_size_',$con_size).'_chain > 0)';

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT product_id, @cnt AS out_counter, @cnt:=IF(@prev_product_id=product_id, @cnt + 1, 0), @prev_product_id:=product_id
        FROM product 
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev_product_id:=0, @cnt:=0) sub1
        WHERE on_amazon = 'on' 
        AND active = 'on'
        $con_check
        ORDER BY product_id";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ( mysql_error() );

while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) 
{
    if ($line['out_counter'] == 1)
    {
        $SKU[] = $line['product_id'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo $line['product_id'].'_'.$line['out_counter']." \r\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Takes your list of $con size and builds up a load of WHERE clauses to check each value is greater than 0. This should save you bringing back values which you don't care about.

The SELECT then brings back items in product_id order, but adds a sequence number (which resets to 0 when the product_id is different from the one on the previous row).

Then when looping around the results it saves the value of product_id if the sequence is 1 (ie the first occurrence of that product_id), else it just outputs the product id with the sequence number concatenated onto the end.